# Conditionally Rendering of Component

Tags: reactjs

I am simulating an async event using setimeout, so after 3sec it pushes a value to the data array.

I am then checking the array length to conditionally render components, but the Loading component does not change even after isEmpty is false. It keeps showing Loading...., which is the first render.

Here is the full code below

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [isEmpty, setisEmpty] = useState(true);
  const data = [];
  
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    data.push('newvalue');
    console.log(data);
    console.log('Array Length: ', data.length);
  }, 
    3000);
    console.log('Array Length: ', data.length);
    if(data.length > 0){
      setisEmpty(false);
    }else{
      setisEmpty(true);
    }
}, [])

    return (
     <>
     {isEmpty ? <h1>Loading...</h1> : <h1>Data Available</h1>}
     </>
  );
}
```

Comment: can you try with removing isEmpty from the dependency matrix of useEffect(I'm guessing based on isEmpty value the useEffect execution won't depend ). Also the html part is within a return block..right ?

Comment: UseEffect runs on every render.  You're triggering re-renders with the state change in your useEffect so you need another approach entirely.  Maybe a child should hold state?  Or the parent should pass a prop?

Comment: @Kaneki21 I have update my question with a complete minimal code

Comment: @jmargolisvt I have update my question with a complete minimal code

Comment: data array has to be used with useState or otherwise you'll lose it on every render, and since you are using isEmpty it will be rerendered. and If you want to check data length after the setTimeout then you can do it inside it only

Comment: Your `if/else` condition is not waiting for the timeout to finish, so it will always go in the `else` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making data a state and then use a useEffect to update the empty flag.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isEmpty, setisEmpty] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const temp = [...data];
      setData([temp, "newvalue"]);
      console.log(data);
      console.log("Array Length: ", data.length);
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Array Length: ", data.length);
    if (data.length > 0) {
      setisEmpty(false);
    } else {
      setisEmpty(true);
    }
  }, [data]);

  return <>{isEmpty ? <h1>Loading...</h1> : <h1>Data Available</h1>}</>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra { inside your map function, may be this is causing the problem.

Comment: I have updated my question with a complete minimal code, for you to test out.